# Combining Multiple Contour Plots with Different X, Y, and Z Ranges

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I am trying to calculate the differences in natural frequencies between two different dynamic models, and I would like to plot these error contours in terms of `ues` (mass ratio) and `nel` (frequency ratio). `err1` corresponds to the error when `nel` > 1 and `err2` corresponds to the error when `nel` < 1.

Naturally these error contours should be plotted on a single graph, but I cannot find a way to combine these on a single graph, especially since `nel` needs to be plotted on a log X-axis. I have tried `Show[]`, but I cannot get it to plot the graph with the following requirements:

1. Logarithmic X-axis (`ues`)
2. Filled in Contours
3. Contour Plot Range (error) shall be {0 , 0.5}
4. X-Axis (`ues`) Range shall be {0 , 1}
5. Y-Axis (`nes`) Range shall be {0 , 3.5}

Here are two separate graphs that accomplish the requirements above but are not combined:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

err1 = -1 + Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[1 + ues + nel^2*(1 + ues) - 
          Sqrt[(1 + ues)*((-1 + nel^2)^2 + (1 + nel^2)^2*
                   ues)]]

err2 = 1 - Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[1 + ues + nel^2*(1 + ues) + 
          Sqrt[(1 + ues)*((-1 + nel^2)^2 + (1 + nel^2)^2*
                   ues)]]

(* Plot Error 1 Contour *)
Show[ContourPlot[
  Tooltip[err1, Row[{"ues = ", ues}]], {ues, 0, 1}, {nel, 1, 3.5}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 0.501}, 
  Contours -> Join[{0.01}, Range[0.05, 0.50, 0.05]], 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}], 
 AxesLabel -> {None, None}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{HoldForm[nel], None}, {HoldForm[ues], None}}, 
 PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]

(* Plot Error 2 Contour *)
Show[ContourPlot[
  Tooltip[err2, Row[{"ues = ", ues}]], {ues, 0, 1}, {nel, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 0.501}, 
  Contours -> Join[{0.01}, Range[0.05, 0.50, 0.05]], 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}], 
 AxesLabel -> {None, None}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{HoldForm[nel], None}, {HoldForm[ues], None}}, 
 PlotLabel -> None, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]
```

Note I use `ScalingFunctions` from Mathematica 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ContourPlot[Tooltip[If[nel <= 1, err2, err1], Row[{"ues = ", ues}]], 
   {ues, 0, 1}, {nel, 0, 3.5}, 
   Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 3.5}, {0, 0.5}}, 
   Contours -> Join[{0.01}, Range[0.05, 0.50, 0.05]], 
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Both `If` or `Piecewise` work beautifully. Thanks for showing me a path foward.

Comment: @felimz, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept and welcome to mma.se.